# How do you get distinct values from dataTables and sum the total specific field using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax, datatables

How do you get the distinct values from dataTables. As you can see from below picture

[image]

You'll see " Course 1 " has the same values. I would like to get all the distinct values from " Course Names " while adding all the equivalent " Students " from the same distinct values in DataTables using JS.

I would like the return would be

" Course 1 , 4 Students "

EDITED :

HTML CODE:

```
<table class="table" id="bookingReport" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead class="thead-inverse">
        <tr>
            <th><h4>Course Names</h4></th>
            <th><h4>Names</h4></th>
            <th><h4>Dates</h4></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>        
</table>
```

JS CODE:

```
"dataSrc": function(result) {
    var obj, id, paymentMethod;
    var validatedResult = [];

    $.each(result.aaData, function(index, value) {
        var givenName, surname, organisationName;

        id = value.id;
        dateCreated = value.dateCreated;



        $.each(value.bookingDetail, function(i, v) {


            $.each(v.student.studentCourseDetail, function(ii, sd) {
                obj = new Object();

                obj["id"] = sd.id;
                obj["surname"] = surname;
                obj["givenName"] = givenName;
                obj["dateCreated"] = dateCreated;
                obj["courseName"] = sd.courseName;


                validatedResult.push(obj);



            });




        });

    });

    return validatedResult;

}, },

"aoColumns": [{
        "data": "courseName"
    }, {
        "data": "givenName"
    }, {
        "data": "dateCreated"
    }

],
```

Comment: Please post your HTML and JS code.

Comment: @gyre : Opps I forgot thanks!. Edited it now btw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To count people assigned to each of the courses you can use `reduce` function of the array. Given below array of student you can easily calculate the result.

```js
var bookingList = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Alice',
    courseName: 'Physics'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Bob',
    courseName: 'Physics'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Emily',
    courseName: 'Math'
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Alice',
    courseName: 'Math'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'Jane',
    courseName: 'Biology'
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: 'Dan',
    courseName: 'Chemistry'
  }
]

var result = bookingList.reduce(function(prevValue, currValue, index, array) {
  var bookingEntry = array[index]
  if (prevValue[bookingEntry.courseName] == null) {
    prevValue[bookingEntry.courseName] = 1
  } else {
    prevValue[bookingEntry.courseName]++
  }

  return prevValue
}, {});

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

Excellent answer from @t3mplar, this is a version using mocked ajax, it also takes into account the possibility of the same course occurring on different dates:

```
"dataSrc": function(data) {
    return data.reduce(function(returnedArray, currentElement, index, originalArray) {
        let foundOne = returnedArray.findIndex(function(element) {
            return currentElement.course === element.course && currentElement.date === element.date
        });
        if (foundOne < 0) {
            returnedArray.push({
                "course": currentElement.course,
                "date": currentElement.date,
                "students": 1
            });
        } else {
            returnedArray[foundOne].students++;
        }
        return returnedArray
    }, []);
}
```

Working JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/L3jrz428/).

Comment: I get the values but it returns

0 : course : "course 1"
     date : "12/12/2016"
     students : 1

1 : course : "course 1"
     date : "12/12/2016"
     students : 1

2 : course : "course 1"
     date : "12/12/2016"
     students : 1

3 : course : "course 1"
     date : "12/12/2016"
     students : 1

I don't know what's wrong with the code attached. Please see 

https://jsfiddle.net/bonjovi123/9onys1hw/#&togetherjs=iu6nfPcxp8

Comment: Updated my JSFiddle to use reduce ;-)